# Update multiple UI component fastly freeze the UI

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

i'm developing a program to monitor an aircraft and my program consist of this component that need to be updated every 30 ms:

- OpenGL 3D model
- 2 Chart with 3 Series
- 3D TeeChart (Chart with x,y, and z axes) [Steema](https://www.steema.com/product/vcl) Product to draw trajectory of aircraft in 3D, and
- Lot of Label and Textbox

all of this component updated based on data that i received from *serialPort* every 30 ms. I have tried **System.Threading** to separate every component update, but this not solve my problem because i need to sleep the thread at least 100 ms before the next update, otherwise the UI will be freeze.

How to solve my problem, is it possible to update the component in real time ?

Comment: You can't.  You have to throttle updates.  Besides, real time to the eye is a bit slower than 30ns.

Comment: so there is no way to solve this problem beside sleep the thread and 
sacrifice the real time ?

Comment: Why would you even want 30ms? Poor CPU. Make it 300ms in it will still be probably invisible to the human eye

Comment: i need to monitor the data in real time especially the 3D TeeChart. if i make it 300ms so i lost 30 data in one second.

Comment: Don't sleep the thread, simply collect your data every 30ms, then every 300 or so ms you update your UI.

Comment: @Will thanks for the suggestion, i have used this before and it's work. but i ask in here for looking the answer "**is it possible to update the component in real time ?**" - every 30 ms
if there is no way, i will keep in this way like your suggestion